# Select statement in datatable using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net, i am trying to filter the data in datatable for that i write select statment and add the row in another table but it is not adding. this is my code:

```
DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
DataTable dt = (DataTable)XMLSerializerBL.Deserialize(xDocTable.OuterXml, XMLSerializerBL.OutputType.DataTable);
//grdsap.DataSource = dt;
//grdsap.DataBind();
string expression = "VKGRP='001'";
DataRow[] rows = dt.Select(expression);

foreach (DataRow thisrow in rows)
{
    //dtnew.Rows.Add(thisrow);+
    //dtnew.ImportRow(thisrow);  
    dtnew.Rows.Add(thisrow.ItemArray);
}
grdmy.DataSource = dtnew;
grdmy.DataBind();
```

Comment: i am not able to add the row into "dtnew" datatable. in "thisrow" row is added but when it is added to [dtnew.rows.add(thisrow.Itemaarry)] it is not added it is showing empty data

Comment: Are you getting an error?  The only thing I see missing is to put dtnew.AcceptChanges() before binging it, but after adding the rows.  But that shouldn't be causing them not to show up. Otherwise, the code looks right to me.I assume you've put a breakpoint in and stepped through the loop to ensure that there are rows to be added, and that it's dtnew.Rows.Add(...) is actually being executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DataView` if you just want filtering:

```
DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
DataTable dt = (DataTable)XMLSerializerBL.Deserialize(xDocTable.OuterXml, XMLSerializerBL.OutputType.DataTable);
DataView dvData = new DataView(dtData);
dvData.RowFilter = "VKGRP='001'";

grdmy.DataSource = dvData;
grdmy.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Both these DataTable objects must have similar column collection.

I assume that the `dt` has two columns.

```
dtnew = new DataTable();
dtnew.Columns.Add("Col1");
dtnew.Columns.Add("Col2");

foreach (DataRow thisrow in rows)
  {
   dtnew.Rows.Add(thisrow[0],thisrow[1]);
  }
```

You can use `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter` to filter the result.

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter="VKGRP='001'";
grdmy.DataSource = dt;
grdmy.DataBind();
```